# Web Service Testing using REST Assured: Failure response received when used parameters in POST request

Tags: rest, rest-assured

I am getting following error when using post request with parameters:

```
{
    "failure":{
        "failureCode":"1035",
        "failureDetails":"Id: null format is not valid",
        "failureInstance":null,
        "failureMessage":"Malformed ID(s) detected.",
        "failureMessageParameter":null
    }
}
```

Following is my code:

```
LoadProperties lp = new LoadProperties();
    @BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest(){
        lp.load();
        RestAssured.keyStore(lp.getProperty("certificatePath"),lp.getProperty("certificatePassword"));
        RestAssured.trustStore(lp.getProperty("cacertsPath"), lp.getProperty("cacertsPassword"));
    }
    @Test
    public void test(){
        RestAssured.baseURI = lp.getProperty("baseURL");
        RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given().header("Authorization", lp.getProperty("AccessToken"));
        request.header("Content-Type","application/json");
        JSONObject json  = new JSONObject();
        try{//**Here I add parameters to json object**
            json.put("", lp.getProperty(""));
            json.put("", lp.getProperty(""));
            json.put("", lp.getProperty(""));
            json.put("", lp.getProperty(""));
            json.put("", lp.getProperty(""));
            json.put("", lp.getProperty(""));
            json.put("", lp.getProperty(""));
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        request.body(json.toString());
        Response response = request.post(lp.getProperty("URL"));
        String statusCode = String.valueOf(response.statusCode());
        System.out.println(response.body().asString());
        Assert.assertEquals(statusCode, "200");
    }
```

However if i use hard coded data(String sData ="{Parameters}") to pass to request body, i get the desired result but not when using json object. I have also tried by converting the json object to jsonString using GSON but still the same response as above.

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: json.put("", lp.getProperty("")); What happens if you put some key and value to your json and not empty strings?

Comment: I do add key and value while sending request and i get the same response. Its just that i can not disclose the parameters here. Apologies for that.

Comment: it is a bit difficult to investigate without full code including entity but are you sure that you send Id in your json body? Looks like your entity has this field and you don't send it

Comment: Yes, I do send ID.

Comment: can you run your test in debug mode and show value json.toString() from request.body(json.toString()); ?